# How to add default namespace to loaded XmlDocument so that validation "works"

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xml-namespaces, xmldocument

We have some xml data that uses a certain namespace, but does not actually declare a namespace for it. We want to validate it, but invalid elements in default namespace don't get caught because `xmlns` is not set so by xml rules anything goes. At this stage of processing document has possibly been loaded for a long time, and is not necessarily in original form anyways (so namespace manager is probably out of the question).

```
<root>
   <valid />
   <notvalid />
</root>
```

```
var xd = new XmlDocument();
xd.Load(xmlstring);
xd.Validate((sender, args) =>
{
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't modify XmlDocument on the fly, because XmlNodes are already created with a certain namespace. You have to modify the document and reparse it/reread via XmlNodeReader.
You can set attributes on XmlDocument, but for namespace they'll actually enforce anything only after reload of document (from modified copy).

```
var target = "urn:foobar";
var xd = new XmlDocument();
xd.Load(xmlstring);

// set default namespace to a schema identifier, 
// this is not enforced in this 'xd' document yet.
xd.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns", target);
var newXd = new XmlDocument();

// reload document into new instance
newXd.Load(xd.OuterXml);

// attach the schema URI to schema identifier
newXd.Schemas.Add(target, "file:///c|/temp/foobar.xsd");
newXd.Validate((sender, args) => {
    ... // now elements in default namespace are validated against "foobar.xsd"
});
```

This probably would be "better" done with XmlNodeReader, LAAEFTR.